# Notice Use of Attributes For Reciprocal Links

Tags: php

I would like to make a link exchange sites. I want to know how my friends treat me the link on its website.
Until now, I have found a php script to detect when I removed the link from its website. But it was not enough for me.

I expected: how can I know if my friend cheating, for example by changing the `rel="dofollow"` into `rel="nofollow"`
In addition, I want to know the title on its website a link that points to a URL `Domain.com`

I would greatly appreciate any input from you.

**While my script code:**

```
<?php
$mydomain = "http://Domain.com"; // Set this to your domain
$list = file_get_contents("list_uri.txt");
$urls = explode ("\n", $list);
echo "<B>Checking $mydomain</B><P><FONT SIZE=-1>";
foreach ($urls as $url) {
if (strlen ($url)) {
echo $url . "<B><FONT COLOR=";
if (strpos (file_get_contents($url), $mydomain) != FALSE) {
echo "GREEN> Link Installed!";
} else {
echo "RED> Link Not Installed!";
}
echo "</FONT></B><BR>";
}
}
echo "</FONT>";
?>
```

Comment: You need to ask a specific question, not just "I would greatly appreciate any input from you". Is the script working? If not, what problem are you having with it?

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks. The script code is working, but only displays the information "Link Installed" or "Link Not Installed". I want to know also the attributes that link, whether `dofollow` or `nofollow`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't know your friends put tabs or some other special chars in their code. You should parse HTML with Simple HTML Dom Parser it's so easy to use :

```
$urlContents = file_get_html($url);
$elements = $urlContents->find('a[rel="dofollow"][href="'.$myDomain.'"]');
if(count($elements) > 0){
    /*Correct structure. You can loop elements with foreach($elements as $element) */
}else{
    //HTML doesn't have on.
}
```

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks. I would first try.

Comment: I still can not wear your code. Maybe I do not know how to use it or did your code is wrong. Thank you..

Comment: You included Simple HTML Dom Parser to your project, right ?